# Algorithm for subtraction of binary numbers

Tags: binary, numbers, subtraction

I am doing a project in C++ and I'm having hard time with substraction of binary numbers. It's easy doing it on paper but in code it's a bit hard for me. 
Can someone please give me the algorithm for the subtraction of two binary numbers? It's supposed to be done WITHOUT conversion to the decimal system.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for doing addition?  If they are signed numbers, what representation are you using?

Comment: Do it in your code as you do it on paper.

Answer (score 2):

```
int subtractBinaries(int x, int y) {
    while (y != 0) {
        int borrow = (~x) & y;
        x = x ^ y;
        y = borrow << 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```